# Mongo C# Driver Not Deleting

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the Mongo U C# driver. I am able to read just fine from the MongoD (and can delete using the Mongo shell).

But when I try to do one of these things:

```
var DeleteOne = await col.DeleteOneAsync(x => (x["student_id"] == studentKey) && (x["score"] == scoreVal));

var DeleteTwo = await col.DeleteOneAsync(
        Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("student_id", studentKey)
        & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("score", scoreVal)
);

var DeleteThree = col.DeleteOne(
        Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("student_id", studentKey)
            & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("score", scoreVal)
        );
```

It returns Acknowledged = true, but DeleteCount = 0.

I've also tried deleting off the _id field, but, again, it can confirm the document exists, but the delete's don't persist.

When I use this exact filter on a find I get the specific row I was looking to delete.

Comment: could you write, how is your collection created? For me this "x["student_id"] " looks a little bit strange, i would await something like x.student_id==studentKey there

Answer (score 1):

I had more or less the same issue but the following works fine for me:

```
var myContext = new MyContext();
var builder = Builders<MyType>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq (x => x.Id, someId);
myContext.MyCollection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);
```